# Unit test - mocking ILogger returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, nunit, moq

I have the following class:

```
    public class UkFileHandler: FileHandler<UkFileHandler.FileMapper>
    {
        public class FileMapper : LookUpFieldDefinition
        {
            public int Name => 1;
            public int Address1 => 4;
            public int Address2 => 5;
        }

        public UkFileHandler(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRecordParser recordParser, 
            IUnzipper unzipper, IFileStore fileStore, IRecordWriter writer) 
            : base(recordParser, unzipper, fileStore, writer)
        {
            Logger = loggerFactory.Create<UkFileHandler>();
        }

        protected override ILogger Logger { get; }
```

I am trying to mock this in my unit test, with my attempt as follows:

```
  [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var mockLoggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
            var mockedILogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
            mockLoggerFactory.Setup(lf=> lf.Create<UkFileHandler>()).Returns(mockedILogger.Object);

            var mockUnzipper = new Mock<IUnzipper>();
            var mockFileStore = new Mock<IFileStore>();
            var mockFileWriter = new Mock<IRecordWriter>();

            var mockFileHandler = new Mock<UkFileHandler>
                                    (mockLoggerFactory.Object, new RecordParser(mockLoggerFactory.Object),
                                    mockUnzipper.Object, mockFileStore.Object, mockFileWriter.Object);
           


            // commented out code which calls method 

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
```

I am using a custom `ILoggerFactory` which looks like this:

```
 public interface ILoggerFactory
    { 
        ILogger Create<T>();
    }
}
```

My issue is that when running my test, the `Logger` instance is Null. I cannot work out where I have missed something here - is anyone able to help?

Comment: Why do you have a custom logger factory? You can inject default logger like this: `ILogger<FooController>`

Comment: Did you verify that the UkFileHandler constructor is actually called?

Comment: Yes it is @KlausGütter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the:

```
protected override ILogger Logger { get; }
```

In your hierarchy, Logger property is virtual or abstract. But there is a simple fix.
Just convert this getter to a full property in `UkFileHandler`. Like this:

```
public class UkFileHandler: FileHandler<UkFileHandler.FileMapper>
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    
    public class FileMapper : LookUpFieldDefinition
    {
        public int Name => 1;
        public int Address1 => 4;
        public int Address2 => 5;
    }

    public UkFileHandler(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRecordParser recordParser, 
        IUnzipper unzipper, IFileStore fileStore, IRecordWriter writer) 
        : base(recordParser, unzipper, fileStore, writer)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.Create<UkFileHandler>();
    }

    protected override ILogger Logger => logger;
}
```

Comment: While I now agree with the cause, given you've changed it to line up with the answer I posted earlier, the remedy would be regarded as bad practice. Avoid updating the SUT to suit the test, especially when Moq has support to handle it. Next time have some conviction and stand by your answer, or give credit where it's due.

Comment: I didn't change my answer. Just edited the text. 
Also this is the second time today you are asking for votes in the answers here. I'm not sure the moderation of stackoverflow allows it.

Comment: I think you're confusing me with someone else, as this is my only post for the last few days. I'm not asking for votes nor does that bother me.

Answer (score 0):

First question would be, is UkFileHandler the SUT? If it is, you wouldn't normally mock it.

The reason it's null is that the Logger property is virtual or abstract. You're overriding it in UkFileHandler, so somewhere in your inheritance hierarchy you will have it marked as virtual or abstract. Once you do that Moq is able to proxy over it and initializes it as the default value (null), even though you're setting it in your constructor.

Couple of ways you could solve it.

Given you are mocking an implementation, `mockFileHandler.CallBase = true;` will allow anything not explicitly set up to work as per the implementation.

The other way would be to set up the Logger property. As it's protected you'd have to do something like the following:

```
mockFileHandler.Protected().Setup<ILogger>("Logger").Returns(mockedILogger.Object);
```